# Formulating the conditional constraint

Tags: modeling, integer-programming, logical-constraints, big-m, indicator-constraints

I want to develop a model extension of capacitated location problem.

The variables are a binary $x_i$ and a continuous $Q_i$. The following condition must be satisfied:

1. if $x_i = 0$, $Q_i$ must be zero.
2. if $x_i = 1$, $Q_i \geq 0$.

How do we formulate it in the integer programming formulation?

Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $M_i$ be an upper bound on $Q_i$, and impose linear big-M constraints
$0 \le Q_i \le M_i x_i$.

Answer (score 2):

I tend to prefer logical constraints to big M unless big M are really needed.

In OPL CPLEX we can write

```
int n=10;
range r=1..n;

dvar boolean x[r];
dvar float+ Q[r];

subject to
{
  forall(i in r) (x[i]==0) => (Q[i]==0);
}
```

Comment: Maybe you know how these constarints are handled in OPL. Are they converted to linear big M constraints or are they imposed through branching? I have often seen very weak LP relaxations and slow progress when improving the bound when I use these logical constraints.

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/difference-between-using-indicator-constraints-and-big-m-formulation

Comment: Thank you very much. That confirmed my own experience and add some additional info.

Comment: Thank you. I use CPLEX for my academic research and teaching. The code is very valuable for me.