# Conditional constraint with a strict inequality

Tags: modeling, integer-programming, cplex, logical-constraints, indicator-constraints

It's almost this question: [Formulating the conditional constraint](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/4715/formulating-the-conditional-constraint)

But there they have non-strict inequality. I have $x_i$ a boolean decision var and $Q_i$ as a nonnegative integer decision variable such that

1. if $x_i = 0$, then $Q_i = 0$
2. if $x_i = 1$, then $Q_i \gt 0$ (note the strict inequality!).

Lets say I dont have upper bound on $Q_i$; is there a mathematical relation between $x_i$ and $Q_i$ you can write directly or is the following way to go?

```
dvar boolean x[I];
dvar int+ Q[I];

subject to
{
  forall(i in I) {
     (x[i]==0) => (Q[i] == 0);
     (x[i]==1) => (Q[i] > 0);
}
```

I can formulate the constraint other way but does it help I'm not sure:

1. if $Q_i = 0$, then $x_i = 0$
2. if $Q_i \gt 0$, then $x_i = 1$.

Comment: If $Q_i$ is an integer variable, then $Q_i > 0$ is equivalent to $Q_i \geq 1$.

Comment: @joni Oh thanks for that heads up! But I'm not sure how to incorporate that... $Q_i \geq x_i$ comes but it allows $Q_i$ be nonzero when $x_i = 0$...

Comment: Are there any upper bounds on the $Q_i$?

Comment: Not really @YukiJ, as I mentioned "Lets say I dont have upper bound on Qi;". What do you have in mind in that case if you don't mind sharing?

Comment: @athing If there was an upper bound $b_i$ you could impose constraints $Q_i\leq b_i x_i$, $Q_i\geq x_i$. If $Q_i=0$, the second constraint forces $x_i=0$ since $x_i$ is a binary variable. If $Q_i=1$ the first constraint would force $x_i=1$ while $Q_i$ is smaller than or equal to its upper bound $b_i$.

Comment: @YukiJ oh thanks! (i think you meant *"if $Q_i \geq 1$..."* for the beginning of the last sentence.) As an aside, do you happen to know those two implications in the for loop in the code above are okay to do in CPLEX? (i'm unable to try now...)

Comment: yes, it should have been $Q_i \geq 1$, sorry! Concerning your code: I have not used Cplex in a while so I am not too sure about the syntax. However, I would definitely advise following @joni's comment to change $Q_i>0$ to $Q_i \geq 1$ in the code.

Comment: @joni You should change your comment to an answer (which should be accepted as the correct answer).

Comment: Assuming that $Q_i >0$ is changed to $Q_i \ge 1$, either pair of implication constraints should work. The catch is that we do not know how CPLEX will use them. It might employ them for branching decisions (e.g., branch on $x_i$ and add $Q_i = 0$ to one child node and $Q_i \ge 1$ to the other), or it might turn them into "big M" constraints (meaning it guesses an upper bound for $Q_i$). Either way, it's hard to predict whether one version will work better than the other.

Comment: By the way, you can (usually) calculate an upper bound for $Q_i$ by relaxing the integrality constraints and maximizing $Q_i$ subject to the constraints. The only two issues here are (1) the LP might be unbounded and (2) if the problem is big enough, solving all those LPs (one for each $i$) might take too much time.

Comment: @prubin thanks for the insights! Do you happen to know those two implications in the for loop in the code above are okay to do in CPLEX? I think the first one is fine but not sure it's still fine when the second implication `>` (or `>=`) comes there... (i don't have access to CPLEX now(adays) sorry...)

Comment: The second implication with >= should be fine. I'm not sure with > whether CPLEX will recognize that $Q > 0$ equates to $Q\ge 1$ or whether it will just reflexively complain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments: If $_i$ is an integer variable, then $_i > 0$ is equivalent to $_i \geq 1$. Hence, you can use the indicator constraints offered by the most commercial solvers in case you don't know upper bounds, i.e. `(x[i]==1) => (Q[i] >= 1)`. Note also [prubin's comment](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/7302/conditional-constraint-with-a-strict-inequality/7307#comment15375_7302) on how one can calculate an upper bound:

> By the way, you can (usually) calculate an upper bound for $Q_i$ by relaxing the integrality constraints and maximizing Qi subject to the constraints. The only two issues here are (1) the LP might be unbounded and (2) if the problem is big enough, solving all those LPs (one for each i) might take too much time.